# SelectListItem/Bound properties overridden the second time a page is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

First time thru code is fine. Second time thru, the Selected value is ignored. See below code:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int MaxTurn = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    List<SelectListItem> TurnList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    // add all turns to turn list
    for (int i = MaxTurn; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        TurnList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
    }
    // make selected item the largest turn
    Model.SelectedTurn = new string(MaxTurn.ToString());
    // if largest turn exists in list, make sure it is selected
    if (TurnList.Exists(f => f.Text.Equals(Model.SelectedTurn)))
    {
        TurnList[TurnList.FindIndex(f => f.Text.Equals(Model.SelectedTurn))].Selected = true;
    }

    // double check - is there a selected item?
    SelectListItem itm = TurnList.Find(f => f.Selected);
    // if it exists, does it equal the max turn?
    if (itm != null && !itm.Value.Equals(MaxTurn.ToString()))
    {// if not, select it...
        TurnList.Select(s => s.Value.Equals(MaxTurn.ToString()));
    }
    else if (itm == null)
    {// otherwise, if nothing is selected, create a null item and make sure the first item is selected
        itm = new SelectListItem { Value = "null", Text = "null" };
        Model.SelectedTurn = new string(TurnList[0].Text);
        TurnList[0].Selected = true;
    }
}

    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <form>
            <strong>Turn #: </strong>@Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.SelectedTurn, TurnList)
            <p>The value of MaxTurn is: @MaxTurn</p>
            <p>The value of the original selected item is: @itm.Value</p>
            <p>The value of the new selected item is: @TurnList.Find(s => s.Selected).Value</p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Does the browser retain the selected item even though I'm resetting the selected value?

Only other relevant code:

```
        public string SelectedTurn { get; set; } = new string("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `random value` generated in each load. `Turnlist` greatest number will then be changed after reloading.

Comment: Yes, the random number generator was put there for testing. The first time thru, everything works correctly, the max value is selected.  The second time thru, if the random number generator returns a value larger, the prior value remains selected. No matter what i do, the maximum value is not selected the second time thru.  Is this a browser persistence issue is what I'm trying to figure out...